# Upgrading Tracking Code to Universal Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm having trouble finding the classic Google Analytics statements I'm looking to upgrade mentioned on the Google Developers guide for upgrading to analytics.js.

What are the replacements for these statements?

```
_gaq.push(['_setCampNameKey', 'id']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageLoadTime']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[_trackPageLoadTime has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageLoadTime) for some time now since pagespeed-tracking is now enabled automatically.

There is no direct replacement for setCampNameKey. You would have to extract the value of your campaign name parameter yourself from the url and assign it via the set method:

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', 'myCampaignName');
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find the answer to this, too, so even though this question is super old, I wanted to leave this here for others to find.

The analytics.js replacement for _setCampNameKey (and the other campaign tracking parameters) can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignName

And this page has a full example of how to implement them:
http://randomproblems.com/how-to-setoverride-campaign-variables-in-google-analytics-universal-with-js/

The example was important for me because I was originally setting them *after* sending the pageview, and it wasn't working.